# Issue with window service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am currently working on hosting the wcf service in window service. The wcf service provides clients to access the database using entity framework. I got them all working. There are two conditions I have been trying which gives me different result.

1) When I hard-coded the database path programmatically in the Service class from windows service to change the datasource dynamically within connection string in app.config file.After executing the code below,  I can get the query data via the service using the web browser which returns the XML document. However, 2) doesn't work for some reason. See the below code for dynamically saving the change of datasource for app.config:

```
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            EntityConnectionStringBuilder efb =
                new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(
                    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["iPhysioAndroidDBEntities1"]
                        .ConnectionString);

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqb =
                new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(efb.ProviderConnectionString);

              **// hard-coded the db path
            sqb.DataSource = "C:\\Users\\Siu W\\Desktop\\data\\iPhysioAndroidDB";**

            efb.ProviderConnectionString = sqb.ConnectionString;
            Console.WriteLine(sqb.ConnectionString);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["iPhysioAndroidDBEntities1"]
                .ConnectionString = efb.ConnectionString;

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

2) When I tried to get the current user name from the machine using System.environment.Username for the full db file path in the same above code, it does return the username of the machine when I put a breakpoint there in debugging mode. However, I cannot get the query result via the service using web browser. It appears "Request Error".

```
   **// dynamically get the user name for the db path
            sqb.DataSource = "C:\\Users\\" + System.Environment.UserName + "\\Desktop\\data\\iPhysioAndroidDB";**
```

The problem is really strange. I have checked that both ways return the same db path, but only the hard-coded one works. Does anyone know the reason of this and how to resolve this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you checked that System.Environment.UserName returns Sui W when it is running normally as the service. According to Microsoft this 'Gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system.' And since services can start before anyone logs on, it sounds like this could be null or undocumented.